# Chrome says I am using illegal function invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, invocation

I'm trying to write some Javascript code that involves a function that calls another function. For some reason, I get an error message in the Chrome dev tools saying, "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" on line 6. However, the function getRequest seems to execute nonetheless and logs "h" to the console. What's going on here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
$(function(){
  $('#search').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchTerm = $('#query').val();
    getRequest();
  });
});

function getRequest(searchTerm){
  console.log("h");
  var params = {
    part: 'snippet',
    key: 'AIzaSyC7oHGfvlIMoEnboos6LZ2b2h_KpPu0u1Q',
    q: $('#searchbox') //searchTerm
  };
  url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';

  $.getJSON(url, params, function(data){
    showResults(data.Search);
    //console.log("x");
  });
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `q: $('#searchbox')`? That passes a jQuery object as a URL parameter, which makes no sense. Did you mean `q: seachTerm`?

Comment: Just wondering: why do you get the searchTerm on line 5, and then not put it as the argument to getRequest() ?

Comment: By the way, the first line of your code does nothing. `$(handler)` does the same thing as `$(document).ready(handler)`. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: So I solved it with LcSalazar's answer. I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some feedback regarding why my question keeps getting downvoted. I thought it was a good question and without the feedback I won't really have any choice but to keep posting questions that will probably also get downvoted until I get banned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a JQuery object as a parameter, and JQuery isn't able to serialize it:

```
    key: 'AIzaSyC7oHGfvlIMoEnboos6LZ2b2h_KpPu0u1Q',
    q: $('#searchbox') //searchTerm
};
```

If it is an input, you can pass its value using `.val()`

```
    key: 'AIzaSyC7oHGfvlIMoEnboos6LZ2b2h_KpPu0u1Q',
    q: $('#searchbox').val() //searchTerm
};
```

**Or**

just use the parameter you are receiving in the method (that's why you created it, isn't it?)

```
getRequest(searchTerm);
```

then

```
    key: 'AIzaSyC7oHGfvlIMoEnboos6LZ2b2h_KpPu0u1Q',
    q: searchTerm
};
```

Comment: LcSalazar is correct as to what the problem is.

Also, the error message is a bit confusing. You have to interpret it as "this exception happened somewhere in the call stack below this call." That is, the illegal invocation happened at some point while executing `getRequest()`.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my original question. Now, however, I'm getting another error message, this one saying, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on line 4. I don't have a clue what it is talking about.

Comment: @FrankTocci - Please, if you have another issue, fell free to post another question addressing to the specific error, in order not to mix the subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Your function 'getRequest' has a 'searchTerm' attribute and you are calling you function without any attributes passed.

```
$(function(){
  $('#search').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchTerm = $('#query').val();
    getRequest(); // Here is the problem
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you mean _parameter_, not _attribute_.

Comment: That may be a problem, but it won't cause the error he's getting. It will just set the parameter to `undefined`.